# find special limit in infinite and compute

Tags: calculus, analysis

find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{n+1}+ \frac{a^\frac{2}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots +\frac{a^\frac{n}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$ when $n\to\infty$  please help me to find it.when $n\to\infty$ it is undefined?

Comment: think in terms of Reimann sums

Comment: Is it $n+\frac{1}{k}$ or $n+k$ in the denominators?

Comment: if $f(x)=\frac{a^x}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ and use sum rieman?

Comment: Good luck with the integral

Comment: Reiman sum works if you have $n+k$ in the denominators but I don't thinlk that this is your case?

Comment: Riemann sums work in both cases. If it is $n+k$ $f(x)=\frac{a^x}{1+x}$ and for $n+\frac{1}{k}$ $f(x)=\frac{a^x}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$. In both cases, I have doubts that the primitive are elementary functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since
$$\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n+1}<\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n+1/i}<\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n}$$
so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n+1}<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n+1/i}<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n}$$
and Note
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a^{i/n}}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{\frac{i}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1}a^xdx=\dfrac{a-1}{\ln{a}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n}a^{\frac{i}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1}a^xdx=\dfrac{a-1}{\ln{a}}$$